# Why do some plants bend their leaves close by night?

Tags: trees

I have a a Tamarind plant that is very young, and it bends its leaves at night and opens them during day.

Why some plants do that? Is it cause the plant feels cold at night? Or this is normal behavior? In either of the cases, what causes them to change the stance?

Comment: ahh. I knew it, but I forgot the reason.No, it is not for the cold. Note it is common on Fabaceae (to have moving leaves, some during hot days, some on nights).

Comment: Can you clarify something  please? By bending the leaves does that mean they curl up and stay in the same position along the stem? If that's what you mean, it might help to change the word "bend" to "close." Or does it mean they bend down and hug closer to the stem? Would you mind adding pictures, one of them during the day and one at night? That would be great. Thanks!

Comment: @sue During Day: https://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fcasaveneracion.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2009%2F08%2Ftamarind-leaves.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fcasaveneracion.com%2Fsoon-my-little-tamarind-tree%2F&docid=EBZ4sKYbOB_3oM&tbnid=R_5-DnOTfcY2pM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwjt8MKYoITXAhUEMY8KHYTfAKwQMwhhKAAwAA..i&w=720&h=480&client=firefox-b-ab&bih=971&biw=1920&q=tamarind%20plant%20leaves&ved=0ahUKEwjt8MKYoITXAhUEMY8KHYTfAKwQMwhhKAAwAA&iact=mrc&uact=8

Comment: @Sue During night: https://previews.123rf.com/images/shakzu/shakzu1209/shakzu120900024/15457416-Macro-closeup-of-tamarind-tree-leaves-on-white-background-Stock-Photo.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No one's entirely sure why some plants do this, but those that do are classed as 'higher' plants (meaning complex or vascular plants, as opposed to lower plants such as algae, moss and the like), and the process itself is called **nyctinasty**. Its a complicated chain of events, some of which are related to detecting different light wavelengths, and others bio chemical reactions. Certainly, Charles Darwin put forward the theory that plants do this for protection from chillier temperatures, but as I said, no one's really sure. You can read more about **nyctinasty** [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyctinasty).

Comment: Lichens, ferns and "the commons" have also some form of it. There are many flowers in many families that flowers at night / cloudy days (e.g. some common Silene), at days, e.g.: Ornithogalum (check the names " nap-at-noon, or eleven-o'clock lady", but maybe she is really posh), etc.

Comment: That's interesting :) It first reminded me of the touch-me-not plant that does the same thing as a defence mechanism. It could be the same for this plant. Like from where the plant originated and developed this mechanism to protect themselves from some nocturnal insects. This was my initial thought. Haha